# How to create a repeating daily local user notification with dynamic properties

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, usernotifications

Here is the scenario I am trying to solve:
In my app the user has the ability to schedule daily, weekly or monthly repeating notifications.
The notification content body and badge number include a dynamic Int property who's value might change daily (numOverdueStents in the example below).
I am struggling with finding a way to fetch and display this dynamic value in the notification each time the notification presents, without launching the app into the foreground.

I tried implementing a UNNotificationAction followed by the didReceive response method of the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate but I have been unsuccessful in achieving my goal.

```
func scheduleNotification (on timeAndDate: Date, scheduleInterval: Int){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    let cdStentLogTVC = CDStentLogTableViewController()
    let numOverdueStents =  cdStentLogTVC.overdueStentCount ?? 0


    //Notification
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "StentLog Notification"

    content.body = "You have: \(numOverdueStents) overdue stents "
    content.badge = NSNumber(integerLiteral: numOverdueStents)
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alert"

    // Action
    let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "show", title: "Overdue Stents?", options: .foreground)
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alert", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

    // Schedule notification interval
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()

    switch scheduleInterval {
    case 0: dateComponents  = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: timeAndDate)
    case 1: dateComponents  = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday], from: timeAndDate)
    case 2: dateComponents  = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday, .day], from: timeAndDate)
    default: dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .weekday, .day], from: timeAndDate)
    }

    // Request
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "StentNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)

}
```

Here are the delegate methods:

```
extension NotificationPublisher: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("The notification is about to present")
    completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .alert])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let identifier = response.actionIdentifier

    switch identifier {
    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("The notification was dismissed")
        completionHandler()
    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
        print("The user opened the app from the notification")
        completionHandler()
    // This is where I was trying to act on the selected action response
    case "show":
        print("Custom action selected")
    default:
        print("The default case was called")
        completionHandler()

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, you cant do it when you app is closed, this means you app cannot process dynamic values. You can save it when your app is alive. Like reminder for specific pre-saved information.

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde, Thank you for commenting. Unlike a reminder with specific pre-saved information, the value of the dynamic property to be displayed in my notifications might be different when the notification is created versus when it is actually displayed. I am looking for a way to retrieve and display this new value each time the notification is displayed (daily vs. weekly vs. monthly).